# Chart won't update in Excel (2007)

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I have an Excel document (2007) with a chart (Clustered Column) that gets its Data Series from cells containing calculated values

The calculated values never change directly, but only as a result of other cells in the sheet changing

When I change other cells in the sheet, the Data Series cells are recalculated, and show new values - but the Chart based on this Data Series refuses to update automatically

I can get the Chart to update by saving/closing, or toggling one of the settings (such as reversing x/y axis and then putting it back), or by re-selecting the Data Series

Every solution I have found online doesn't work

- Yes I have Calculation set to
  automatic
- Ctrl+Alt+F9 updates everything fine, EXCEPT the chart
- I have recreated the chart several times, and on different computers
- I have tried VBA scripts like:

  `Application.Calculate`
  `Application.CalculateFull`
  `Application.CalculateFullRebuild`
  `ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll`
  `DoEvents`

None of these update or refresh the chart

I do notice that if I type over my Data Series, actual numbers instead of calculations, it will update the chart - it's as if Excel doesn't want to recognize changes in the calculations

Has anyone experienced this before or know what I might do to fix the problem?
Thank you

Comment: What type of Chart are you using?

Comment: Ah yes forgot to mention that, its a Clustered Column Chart

Comment: Belongs on SuperUser. Not programming-related.

Comment: Check if your status bar shows the message "Calculate". Remember to answer comments prepending @Username

Comment: Is this the same issue I described in a post a few months ago?: [MS Excel Charts Do Not Automatically Update When Data Changes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4466152/ms-excel-charts-do-not-automatically-update-when-data-changes)

Comment: This question was asked 5 years ago, and it's still not been fixed in Excel 2016. Unbelievable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have run into this same issue - not sure why, and when it happens the only way I have ever gotten the chart to force update is to change something in the chart definition itself, which can easily be done via VBA as in:

```
Dim C As ChartObject: Set C = Me.ChartObjects("chart name")
C.Chart.ChartTitle.Text = C.Chart.ChartTitle.Text + "1"
```

There may be a better answer that gets to the bottom of the problem - but I thought this might help.  Working on the sheet I would do a quick Ctrl-X, Ctrl-V on a piece of the chart (or the whole thing) to force the chart to update.

Comment: Beware of using `+` for string concatenation! Should use `&`.

Answer (score 15):

This is the only thing I've found to consistently update a chart.  It cuts the root cause of the problem (I assume): the series data is getting cached in the chart.  By forcing the chart to re-evaluate the series, we are clearing the cache.

```
' Force the charts to update
Set sht = ActiveSheet
For Each co In sht.ChartObjects
    co.Activate
    For Each sc In ActiveChart.SeriesCollection
        sc.Select
        temp = sc.Formula
        sc.Formula = "=SERIES(,,1,1)"
        sc.Formula = temp
    Next sc
Next co
```

Comment: This worked for me! I tried 10 other solutions before I tried this

Comment: I found that you can just `Activate` each chart and that's enough to "refresh" it - No need to iterate through each chart's series.  (Well aware that this answer is over a decade old, so perhaps this wasn't always the case, but just wanted to share what I'm seeing now.)

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem while generating 1000+ graphs through `VBA`. I generated the graphs and assigned a range to their series. However, when the sheet recalculated the graphs wouldn't update as the data ranges changed values.

**Solution** --> I turned WrapText off before the For...Next Loop that generates the graphs and then turned it on again after the loop.

```
Workbooks(x).Worksheets(x).Cells.WrapText=False
```

and after...

```
Workbooks(x).Worksheets(x).Cells.WrapText=True
```

This a great solution because it updates 1000+ graphs at once without looping through them all and changing something individually.

Also, I'm not really sure why this works; I suppose when WrapText changes one property of the data range it makes the graph update, although I have no documentation on this.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem with a simple pie chart.

None of the macros worked that I tried. Nothing worked on `cut`, `pasting`, `relocating` chart.

The Workaround I found was to edit the chart text, remove the labels, then re-select the labels.  Once they re-appeared, they were updated.

Comment: This fix worked for me, with a slight modification. Set `Data Labels = None`. Set `Data Labels = Bottom`. Reformat to taste. (Excel 2010)

Answer (score 3):

This is an absurd bug that is severely hampering my work with Excel.

Based on the work arounds posted I came to the following actions as the simplist way to move forward...

Click on the graph you want update - Select CTRL-X, CTRL-V to cut and paste the graph in place... it will be forced to update.

Answer (score 3):

Ok I have a solution, really....

I found that the problem with my charts not updating first occurred shortly after I had hidden some data columns feeding the chart, and checked "show data hidden in rows and columns" in the Chart's "Select Data Source" msg box).

I found that if I went back into the "Select Data Source" msg box and unchecked/rechecked the "show data hidden in rows and columns" that the chart refreshes.

Programatically I inserted the following into a Macro that I linked a button to, it refreshes all of my charts quick enough for a workaround to a known bug.  This code assumes one chart per worksheet but another for statement for charts 1 to N could be added if desired:

```
Sub RefreshCharts()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For I = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

Worksheets(I).Activate

    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate

    ActiveChart.PlotVisibleOnly = True

    ActiveChart.PlotVisibleOnly = False

Next I

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Can't believe it.. I've been struggling (seriously!) with an application in which im fetching equity prices and pushing them into a chart (using array in VBA and hence no range inside a worksheet). When changing from one chart type (line, charttype = 51) to another (equity chart, charttype = 89)  the equity chart series wouldnt show. I could manually force them to show by selecting "choose data" and simply double click a data series, after which all the data would become visible. Before it, even accessing xvalues in vba stated an empty series. The `plotvisibleonly = true/false` solved it!

Answer (score 2):

This works very well for me -- it flips axes on all charts and then flips them back, which causes them to refresh without changing at all.

```
'Refresh all charts
For Each mysheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    mysheet.Activate
    For Each mychart In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects
        mychart.Activate
        ActiveChart.PlotArea.Select
        ActiveChart.PlotBy = xlRows
        ActiveChart.PlotBy = xlColumns
        ActiveChart.PlotBy = xlRows
    Next
Next
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a known Excel bug...

The best and fastest workaround is the `Columns.AutoFit` - Trick:

```
Sub Update_Charts()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Temp = ActiveCell.ColumnWidth
    ActiveCell.Columns.AutoFit
    ActiveCell.ColumnWidth = Temp
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

I have another problem of refeshing charts. When generating the charts automatically, some charts appear over and cache the text in the sheet. It happens to be a problem of refreshing the generated charts. When I zoom in or zoom out, I can get the expected results. So I post the solution here if it interest someone.
Programmatically, I added this after generating charts :

```
ActiveWindow.Zoom = ActiveWindow.Zoom + 1
ActiveWindow.Zoom = ActiveWindow.Zoom - 1
```

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue. The issue is due to restriction in no. of calculated formulas in your sheet. you can solved it using two ways:

**Manual force re-calculate:**

```
Press SHEFT + F9
```

**Macro to force re-calculate:**
add below code to the end of the function which changes the data

```
Activesheet.Calculate
```

**I found the solution of it:**
From excel options make sure to change the calculation options as below. It changed sometimes to manual after heavy work in excel.

[image: Auto Calculation]

Comment: I had the same problem in Excel 2013 and this solution really worked. I can't understand how this setting changed to **Manual** when I am absolutely sure it was **Automatic** several day ago.

Comment: It usually changed to Manual after excessive use specially if you've huge data in sheet with formulas. It seems it is kind of precaution action taken by Excel to avoid crashing.

Answer (score 2):

We found a solution that doesn't involve VBA: multiplying some element of the chart's data range by `TODAY()-TODAY()+1`.

Even though the range was recalculating without this, the volatile nature of `TODAY()` somehow gives it an extra boost that triggers the chart recalc.

Comment: This is of course a horrible hack. But it does work (on second calculation pass, for some reason) in my case; I used `& T(NOW())` instead but it's the same principle. Obviously this would be a terrible idea if there are a lot of calcs depending on your now super-volatile cell, but results in an `xlsx` that can be sent to people who are paranoid about `xlsm`s and will still have the right data in.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is ridiculous! No one's solution worked for me in 2010, but I based mine off of tpascale's:

```
Dim C As ChartObject
Set C = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("CTR_Chart")
C.Chart.SetSourceData Source:=Range( _
    "KeywordBreakdown!$A$8:$A$12,KeywordBreakdown!$E$8:$E$12")
```

Simply redefined the Source Data range. If it's a named range, that could conceivably be reasonably clean. I guess the best solution to this is keep trying to modify different chart properties until it refreshes.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and found that it was caused by having two excel applications running at the same time. If I closed everything and opened just the file I was having problems with the charts where dynamic like they should be. Maybe this helps

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me,  it cuts and re-pastes the charts on the active worksheet. I based this off of Jason's code and a [blog post](http://peltiertech.com/Excel/ChartsHowTo/ResizeAndMoveAChart.html) I found in a quick Google search.

```
Sub RepasteCharts()

Dim StrTemp As String
Dim IntTempTop As Integer
Dim IntTempLeft As Integer


Set sht = ActiveSheet

For Each co In sht.ChartObjects
    'Activate the chart
    co.Activate

    'Grab current position on worksheet
    IntTempTop = ActiveChart.Parent.Top
    IntTempLeft = ActiveChart.Parent.Left

    'Cut and paste
    ActiveChart.Parent.Cut
    ActiveSheet.Paste

    'Reposition to original position
    ActiveChart.Parent.Top = IntTempTop
    ActiveChart.Parent.Left = IntTempLeft
Next co


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

From Excel 2013 on, there is the `Chart.Refreh` method (https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/office/ff198180.aspx) which worked for me:

```
Dim cht As ChartObject
For Each cht In ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.ChartObjects
    cht.Chart.Refresh
Next cht
```

Answer (score 0):

Just spent half a day on this myself.

I have a macro that changes values that are the data for a chart. All worked fine in Excel 2003, but in Excel 2007 the chart seems to lose all connection to its data, although manually changing data values in two column triggered a recalc.

My solution has been to make all charts on the active sheet invisible before the change in data, then make them visible again and call chart refresh for good measure. ( It only seems to be visible charts that have this problem updating ).

This works for me and also handles similar issues with charts as well as chart objects. The refresh may not be necessary - more testing needed.

```
Dim chrt As Chart
Dim chrtVis As XlSheetVisibility
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim bChartVisible() As Boolean
Dim iCount As Long

Dim co As ChartObject

On Error Resume Next

Set chrt = ActiveChart

If Not chrt Is Nothing Then
        chrtVis = chrt.Visible
        chrt.Visible = xlSheetHidden
        End If

Set sht = ActiveSheet

If Not sht Is Nothing Then
        ReDim bChartVisible(1 To sht.ChartObjects.Count) As Boolean
        iCount = 1
        For Each co In sht.ChartObjects
            bChartVisible(iCount) = co.Visible
            co.Visible = False
            iCount = iCount + 1
            Next co
        End If
```

**DO MACRO STUFF THAT CHANGES DATA**

```
If Not sht Is Nothing Then
        iCount = 1
        For Each co In sht.ChartObjects
            co.Visible = bChartVisible(iCount)
            co.Chart.Refresh
            iCount = iCount + 1
        Next co
        End If

If Not chrt Is Nothing Then
        chrt.Visible = chrtVis 
        chrt.Refresh
        If chrt.Visible Then
            chrt.Select
            End If
        End If

On Error GoTo 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as the poster. Basically I'm running a dashboard, and I have a bunch of named ranges that are populated with return values from some UDFs. On the dashboard, there are some pie charts with data series tied to cells which contain these named ranges (the problem also occurs if the data series target cells contain the UDFs directly, bypassing the named ranges).

I change a cell value which contains, for example, the date range to base the dashboard on, and the named ranges and UDFs are forced to calculate. However, the pie charts do not update--for some reason, other types of charts do. And by the way, these are chart objects, not chart sheets. Anyway, let's cut to the solution:

I didn't want to visibly change the chart title or some other aspect of it, and anyway I noticed this wasn't updating my charts consistently. Sometimes the first time I triggered the calculation the pies would update, but with subsequent calculations the pies would not. I did notice, however, that every time I made a change in the code my dashboard worked. Thus:

**Solution:**

```
With ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("ThisWorkbook").CodeModule

     .AddFromString "'test"
     .DeleteLines 1

End With
```

If you're using the Workbook module (I wasn't in this case), just create a new module and reference that instead.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem with my work last week when I added some more calculation to my sheet. After that, using radio buttons to select data to be presented on graphs did not update the graphs anymore.

The best explanation I have been able to find so far is this:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/243495

If I understood it right, if there are more than 65536 formulas that have another cell as a reference in your file, Excel starts to optimize the calculation and in some cases graphs don't update correctly anymore.

If there is a workaround for this without using VBA macros, I would be glad to hear that (can't use those as the files need to be shared through SharePoint without VBA macros).

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was using a macro to insert/remove a column in the data table for the chart. This will cause the chart to update the data selection.

I found this to be the fastest way to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem while working through a tutorial (very frustrating when you follow the steps and don't get the expected result).

The tutorial to create a pie chart wanted me to select range `A3:A10`, then also select non-adjacent range `E3:E10`. I did so. I got the chart.

It then asked me to change a value and watch the percentage change, then to look at the pie chart and see the update.

It didn't update.

I looked at the data source for the pie chart, and the range was bizarre. It had the `A3:A10` range notated properly, but the `E10` cell reference repeated several times, and it had all of the `E` cells listed in a random order. It looked like

```
=SERIES(,(Revenue!$A$3:$A$10,Revenue!$E$3,Revenue!$E$10,Revenue!$E$10,Revenue!$E$10,Revenue!$E$10,Revenue!$E$10,Revenue!$E$9,Revenue!$E$8,Revenue!$E$7,Revenue!$E$6,Revenue!$E$5,Revenue!$E$4),1
```

I changed the data source to read:

```
=SERIES(,Revenue!$A$3:$A$10,Revenue!$E$3:$E$10,1)
```

Problem solved. Sometimes it's a matter of cleaning up your code so the calculations processor has less to sort through.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this problem, too. Finally solved it by recalculating the sheet that has the chart data AFTER the custom function has recalculated. So, in Sheet 1, I have a cell that contains

```
=ComputeScore()
```

In the VBA module, the function is defined as Volatile, to ensure that ComputeScore() runs after any updates to the spreadsheet.

```
Function ComputeScore() As Double
    Application.Volatile True
    . . . do some stuff to get a total . . .
    ComputeScore = theTotal
End Function
```

Then, in the VBA of Sheet 1, this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    'Recalculate the charts data page to force the charts to update.
    'Otherwise, they don't update until the next change to a sheet, and so
    'chart data is always one update behind the user's data changes.
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Calculation = xlManual
    Sheets("Charts Data").Calculate
    Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

So, the sheet named Charts Data, which references the custom function cell of Sheet 1, will do a recalculation AFTER the ComputeScore() function has updated the cell of Sheet 1, since Worksheet_Calculate() fires after the ComputeScore() recalc. This additional round of calculation of the chart data causes the chart to update now, rather than later or not at all. The setting of EnableEvents and xlManual keeps infinite recalc loops and other event problems from occurring.

Answer (score 0):

This might look extremely basic but I just tried Manual Calculating on the spreadsheet where the charts were (by pressing F9) and it worked! Tha VBA code for it is simply:

Calculate

;)

Answer (score 0):

As i tried pretty much ALL the presented solutions and since none worked in my case, I'll add my two cents here as well. Hopefully it helps someone else.

The consensus on this issue seems to be that we need to somehow force excel to redraw the graph since it is not doing it when it should.

My solution was to kill the X-Axis data and replace it with nothing, before changing it to what i wanted. Here my code:

```
With wsReport
    .Activate
    .ChartObjects(1).Activate
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = "=" 'Kill data here
        .Range("A1").Select 'Forwhatever reason a Select statement was needed
        .ChartObjects(1).Activate
        ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = "=tblRef[Secs]"
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

My two cents for this problem--I was having a similar issue with a chart on an Access 2010 report. I was dynamically building a querydef, setting that as the rowsource on my report and then trying to loop through each series and set the properties of each series. What I eventually had to do was to break out the querydef creation and the property setting into separate subs. Additionally, I put a

```
SendKeys ("{DOWN}")
SendKeys ("{UP}")
```

at the bottom of each of the two subs.

Answer (score 0):

On changing the values of the source data, chart was not getting updated accordingly. Just closed all instances of excel and restarted, problem disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem - Charts didn't appear to update.  I tried just about everything on this thread with no luck.  I finally realized that the charts that I was copying and pasting were linked to the source data, and that is why they were all showing the same results.

Be sure you are copying and pasting pictures before you go through all the other motions....

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem, and also found that the line would only display if I put in bad data (characters instead of numbers).  This caused the line to appear, but changing back to valid data caused it to disappear again.

What I found is that if I double-clicked the line (appearing with bad data), it showed me that it was on the SECONDARY axis for some reason.  Changing that to PRIMARY axis solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Charts are not "feeling" changes with direct inserting values to source cells with macro. You must send values out of chart cells, and after this use code like this

Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A1:K1")=Worksheets("sheet2").Range("A4:K4").Value

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem today with a 2010 file with a large number of formulas and several database connections. The chart axis that were not updating references ranges with hidden columns, similar to others in this chain, and the labels displayed the month and year "MMM-YY" of the dynamic data. I tried all solutions listed except for the VBA options as I'd prefer to solve without code.

I was able to solve the issues by encapsulating my dates (the axis labels) in a TEXT formula as such: =TEXT(A10,"MMM-YY"). And everything immediately updates when values change. Happy days again!!!

From reading the other contributors issues above I started to think that the Charts were having problems with the DATE data type specifically, and therefore converting the values to text with the TEXT function resolved my issue. Hopefully this may help you as well. Just change the format within the double quotes (second argument of the TEXT function) to suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Just activate the sheet where the chart is:

```
Sheets(1).Activate
```

and your problem disappears.

I had the same problem and none of the things you mentioned in question worked for me until I just activated sheet. The accepted answer didn't work for me neither.

Alternatively you can make:

```
ActiveCell.Activate
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the macro didn't update the x-axis for all series, but only the first one. The solution I found was to update the x-axis for all series and then it refrehsed (also I had code to change the format of the x-axis, but I don't think that that was the problem).

```
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Diagram 7").Activate
ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).Select
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "={""""}"
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "=YYY!$BQ$85:$BQ$8844"
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).XValues = "=YYY!$BQ$85:$BQ$8844"
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(3).XValues = "=YYY!$BQ$85:$BQ$8844"
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(4).XValues = "=YYY!$BQ$85:$BQ$8844"
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(5).XValues = "=YYY!$BQ$85:$BQ$8844"
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(6).XValues = "=YYY!$BQ$85:$BQ$8844"
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(7).XValues = "=YYY!$BQ$85:$BQ$8844"
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(8).XValues = "=YYY!$BQ$85:$BQ$8844"
```

Full macro;

```
Sub TEST()
'
' TEST Makro
'
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Diagram 7").Activate
ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).Select
Selection.TickLabels.NumberFormat = "@"
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Diagram 7").Activate
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "={""""}"
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "=YYY!$BQ$85:$BQ$8844"
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).XValues = "=YYY!$BQ$85:$BQ$8844"
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(3).XValues = "=YYY!$BQ$85:$BQ$8844"
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(4).XValues = "=YYY!$BQ$85:$BQ$8844"
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(5).XValues = "=YYY!$BQ$85:$BQ$8844"
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(6).XValues = "=YYY!$BQ$85:$BQ$8844"
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(7).XValues = "=YYY!$BQ$85:$BQ$8844"
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(8).XValues = "=YYY!$BQ$85:$BQ$8844"
ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).Select
ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).TickMarkSpacing = 730
ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).TickLabelSpacing = 730
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, first disabling and then re-enabling calculation (e.g. for the active worksheet) solved the problem:

```
ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.EnableCalculation = False
ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.EnableCalculation = True
```

Maybe execute twice in succession.
All charts in the worksheet update entirely.

Answer (score 0):

To update a chart just put a Sheets("Sheet1").Calculate into your sub procedure. If you have more charts on different tabs, then just create a worksheet loop.

Answer (score 0):

With Excel 2013, I have encountered the same problem, but it seems related to some (self-made) Add-Ins I'm using, which add a tab to the ribbon. After unhooking these AddIns in the Options > Add-Ins > Goto: Exce-Add-Ins > Add_Ins Box **and restarting Excel** (!), all charts in the workbook kept updating immediately. But as soon as I activate (hook) one of these Add-Ins, none of the charts would update anymore.
This issue does not show up with other Add-Ins (like e.g. Solver), so I still have to find out if it is caused by the Add-In creating an additional Tab in the ribbon, or just any Add-In of .xlam - type.

Only by help of following workaround code I could persuade the charts to do their job:

```
Dim chtChart As ChartObject

For Each chtChart In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects
   chtChart.Chart.ChartWizard
Next chtChart
```

Strange enough, the *.Chart.Refresh* - method didn't work either, but *.Chart.ChartWizard* did, though no parameters are given so it doesn't change anything!

(And yes, the calculation method of the workbook *was / still is automatic*)

---

update (2019-09-17):

Since another (3rd party) Add-In did NOT prevent any charts from updating, I plunged into some further research, disabled all code, deleted all XML-contents of the customUI - ribbon and removed all relations to external libraries (as far as the VBE let me do). Still I could reliably prevent all charts from updating just by activating this now completely useless Add-In.

As a last try, I re-built the Add-In from scratch by copying all code into a fresh .xlam - file, set all required library relations and finally added the XML-code for the ribbon with the customUI - editor.

And behold!: now all charts kept updating :-D

---

So - without proof - I just can guess that my old AddIn (originally of 2011, so probably done with Excel 2007 or 2010) was not completely compatible with Excel 2013. So it's always a good idea to do a new setup / re-create any AddIn with the present version of Excel ;-)

Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

I found that by creating the chart in a separate worksheet any updates will apply. HTH

Comment: You may have been downvoted because the OP mentioned that he had tried it on multiple computers. Tricky issue in any case :)