# Excel 2010 chart axis number format doesnt update

Tags: excel, vba, charts, excel-2010

I have an annoying problem about updating decimal separator in chart axis after changing the international settings, for example when switching from "." to ",". 
Decimal separator changes in cells normally, but it does not change in labels of a chart axis.
Restarting excel solves the problem.

But is it really necessary to restart excel? I would be happy to do it without the restart, because I am creating an utility allowing other users to print under english or czech language settings and restarting the excel is unwanted here.

I found several discussions related to the topic, but it is not exactly what I need and I did not find a solution there (hope I did not miss anything), for example

[Chart axis custom number format localization in Excel 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9130361/chart-axis-custom-number-format-localization-in-excel-2010) 
[Excel chart won't update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4902703/excel-chart-wont-update)
[Wrong decimal separator in charts](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-excel/excel-2010win7-wrong-decimal-separator-in-charts/982763ba-73c5-4d4e-831f-0c04038b6dcd)

What is even more surprising is that if I create a whole new chart it also displays the original decimal separator, not the new one I set.

Thanks for any advice, p.

[image: situation]

Comment: I didn't understand. The old chart does not update, ok. But the new chart, it keeps the same as the old or does it update?

Comment: also, if you have a picture that helps explain, you can put the link in, and a higher rep user may add the image for you

Comment: I will try to write more clearly next time. I edited the question and added link to the picture. Both the charts have the original decimal separator, not the new one I set.

Comment: I know it's late.. but 1.2 is on your x-axis... you've changed your x value not the y-value, that's why the graph is not changing.

Comment: @kpark91 you are right, I overlooked that, now it should be ok. But as you can see, the problem still prevails. I have not found a solution yet.