# VBA - Sparkline with Dynamic Range Not Updating in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, sparklines

I have a question extremely similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4902703/1693085), where I have:

1. Created a worksheet with a sparkline on it which references a dynamic range
2. I have a macro that, via a loop, updates some cells (and therefore changes the sparkline with each loop iteration)
3. Copies a large range (including the sparkline and other named ranges)
4. Pastes this range in a second sheet (I couldn't figure out how to do it any other way, so I'm using the `Range.CopyPicture` method and pasting the range as a picture to the second sheet, but if there's a way you know to paste the sparkline itself such that it won't be updated when I update the raneg again, PLEASE let me know)

Now, my problem is that if I step through the code in debug mode, everything works out well, BUT if I let the macro run automatically, the sparkline never gets updated (so it always looks like it did the first time the macro runs).

As a simple example of my problem, suppose I have this in my worksheet:

```
Cells A1-A10: 
      1,2,3...,10 (what I'll use for the sparkline range)

Cell Named "StartCol": 
      =RANDBETWEEN(1,9)

Cell Named "Width":    
      =RANDBETWEEN(1,10-StartCol)

Dynamic range Named "SparkRange":  
      =OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$1,0,StartCol-1,1,Width)

Cell With a SparkLine within a larger range Named "ToCopy"

A Second Sheet Named "OutPut" with a named range "Output" where we'll start pasting to
```

---

Now, simplistic VBA code:

```
Sub Test()
    Sheets("Output").Select

    For i = 1 To 10
        Application.Calculate   ' Probably not needed, but putting it in to be safe
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("ToCopy").CopyPicture

        Sheets("Output").Range("Output").Select
        Sheets("Output").Paste
        Sheets("Output").Names("output").RefersTo = Sheets("Output").Range("Output").Offset(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("ToCopy").Rows.Count + 2)
    Next i
End Sub
```

---

Now, this SHOULD paste in 10 different sparklines, but it rather pastes 10 copies of the same one. AND If I step through it in debug mode (or even set a breakpoint and then hit `F5` in VBA, then it works!)
Again, I looked at the question mentioned above and tried its tricks to no avail.... Any one know how to get this to work for sparklines????

Thanks SO MUCH!!!

Comment: BIRDSVIEW: If it works in debug mode then try this. Add `Doevents` so that it gets enough time to place the image in the clipboard and then paste it?

Comment: @SiddharthRout... Just tried it... No luck :( Any other ideas???? - This one's hurting!!

Comment: OMG - @SiddharthRout... I TAKE THAT BACK!!!! - I put it in another location **AND IT WORKED**

Comment: Glad it worked for you :D

Comment: **YOU ARE MY HERO!!!** - Please just post it as a solution so I can give you credit!! - I can't tell you how much fristration you saved me!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are continuously doing a repetitive exercise which involves excel/system to process multiple events then it is advisable to separate them using `DoEvents`.

For example in your case, you need to give enough time for Excel to copy the image into Clipboard and then paste it back.

For example

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("ToCopy").CopyPicture

Doevents '<~~ This gives enough time for the pic to be placed in Clipboard

Sheets("Output").Paste

DoEvents '<~~ This gives enough time for the pic to be pasted
```

In more technical terms, `DoEvents` surrenders execution of the macro so that the operating system can process other events. The `DoEvents` function passes control from the application to the operating system.

**CAUTION**: Judicious use of `DoEvents` is preferred else you will end up slowing your code unnecessarily.