# Application.ScreenUpdating not working when updating/changing charts?

Tags: excel, vba, charts, updates

I have a worksheet with several charts with vertical bars representing statistical data.
When the excel file is opened, it updates all the charts by deletting, then putting the data back in place. (it is necessary as the data can have been changed previously)

The macro starts with a "Application.ScreenUpdating = False", and at the end (see code) we call the functions updating the charts. each function starts with a Application.ScreenUpdating = false and finished with a Application.ScreenUpdating = true...

I tried to delete these Application.ScreenUpdating as the main calling function already got the Application.ScreenUpdating = T/F, but it changes nothing, we see each data of the charts being removed and put back, one by one...

This should not happen :-(

here is the code :

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
'''When the file is opened

Application.ScreenUpdating = False 

'Putting back all macro buttons and comboboxes in the right place
'##############################################################################
Worksheets("Comparaison").ComboBox1.Left = 474
Worksheets("Comparaison").ComboBox1.Height = 25.5
Worksheets("Comparaison").ComboBox1.Width = 99
Worksheets("Comparaison").ComboBox1.Top = 64.5

'Etc Etc

'##############################################################################
Worksheets("Dealer_comparaison").ComboBox1.Left = 474
Worksheets("Dealer_comparaison").ComboBox1.Height = 25.5
Worksheets("Dealer_comparaison").ComboBox1.Width = 99
Worksheets("Dealer_comparaison").ComboBox1.Top = 69

'Etc etc

Worksheets("Dealer_comparaison").ComboBox1.Clear
Worksheets("Dealer_comparaison").ComboBox2.Clear
Worksheets("Dealer_comparaison").ComboBox3.Clear
Worksheets("Dealer_comparaison").ComboBox4.Clear
Worksheets("Dealer_comparaison").ComboBox5.Clear
Worksheets("Dealer_comparaison").ComboBox6.Clear

'##############################################################################
'"Data from" combo box
Worksheets("Dealer_detail").ComboBox1.Left = 474
Worksheets("Dealer_detail").ComboBox1.Height = 25.5
Worksheets("Dealer_detail").ComboBox1.Width = 99
Worksheets("Dealer_detail").ComboBox1.Top = 64.5

'Etc etc
'##############################################################################

'"Data from" combo box
Worksheets("Drv.Km-Evol").DrivenKmCombo.Left = 1.5
Worksheets("Drv.Km-Evol").DrivenKmCombo.Height = 21
Worksheets("Drv.Km-Evol").DrivenKmCombo.Width = 64.5
Worksheets("Drv.Km-Evol").DrivenKmCombo.Top = 62.25

'##############################################################################

'Filling the comboboxes with the years
For i = 1 To Sheets.Count 'Going through all the sheets
    If IsNumeric(Sheets(i).Name) Then 'Putting all year sheets in combobox
        Worksheets("Comparaison").ComboBox1.AddItem Sheets(i).Name
        Worksheets("Comparaison").ComboBox2.AddItem Sheets(i).Name

        Worksheets("Dealer_comparaison").ComboBox1.AddItem Sheets(i).Name
        Worksheets("Dealer_comparaison").ComboBox2.AddItem Sheets(i).Name

        Worksheets("Dealer_detail").ComboBox1.AddItem Sheets(i).Name
        Worksheets("Dealer_detail").ComboBox2.AddItem Sheets(i).Name

        Worksheets("Drv.Km-Evol").DrivenKmCombo.AddItem Sheets(i).Name
    End If
Next

'Filling the combobox with the Regions in Dealer_comparaison
i = 4
last_region = "test"
Do While Not IsEmpty(Worksheets("Dealer_comparaison").Range("BD" & i)) 'Going through all the regions
    If last_region <> Worksheets("Dealer_comparaison").Range("BD" & i).Value Then 'Region only counted once
        Worksheets("Dealer_comparaison").ComboBox7.AddItem Worksheets("Dealer_comparaison").Range("BD" & i).Value 'Adding the region
        Worksheets("Dealer_detail").ComboBox7.AddItem Worksheets("Dealer_comparaison").Range("BD" & i).Value 'Adding the region
        last_region = Worksheets("Dealer_comparaison").Range("BD" & i).Value 'Region already counted
    End If
    i = i + 1
Loop

'Filling the combobox with the dealers in Dealer_detail
J = 37
last_Dealer = "test"
Worksheets("Dealer_detail").DealerDisplayCombo.AddItem "*All*"
Worksheets("Dealer_detail").DealerDisplayCombo.Value = "*All*"
Do While Not IsEmpty(Worksheets("Dealer_detail").Range(Split(Cells(1, J).Address, "$")(1) & 3)) 'Going through all the dealers
    If last_Dealer <> Worksheets("Dealer_detail").Range(Split(Cells(1, J).Address, "$")(1) & 3).Value Then 'Region only counted once
        Worksheets("Dealer_detail").DealerDisplayCombo.AddItem Worksheets("Dealer_detail").Range(Split(Cells(1, J).Address, "$")(1) & 3).Value 'Adding the region
        last_Dealer = Worksheets("Dealer_detail").Range(Split(Cells(1, J).Address, "$")(1) & 3).Value 'Region already counted
    End If
    J = J + 1
Loop

'Filling the combobox with the min distances in every sheet
Worksheets("Comparaison").MinDistCombo.Value = 10
For MinDist = 0 To 200 Step 10
    Worksheets("Comparaison").MinDistCombo.AddItem MinDist 'Adding the region
    Worksheets("Dealer_comparaison").MinDistCombo.AddItem MinDist 'Adding the region
    Worksheets("Dealer_detail").MinDistCombo.AddItem MinDist 'Adding the region
Next


'update the data in case the years tabs have been changed
'this calls functions that update the data in the pages, but even before this, the screen is already showing the updates.
'moreover, each function called got a Application.ScreenUpdating = false at the beginning

'Call Functionthatdonteexist

Worksheets("Comparaison").Activate
Call Sheet1.ChangeComboBox1
Call Sheet1.ChangeComboBox2

Worksheets("Dealer_comparaison").Activate
Call Sheet2.ChangeComboBox1
Call Sheet2.ChangeComboBox2
Call Sheet2.ChangeComboRegion


Worksheets("Dealer_detail").Activate
Call Sheet6.ChangeComboBox1
Call Sheet6.ChangeComboBox2

Worksheets("Comparaison").Activate
Worksheets("Comparaison").Range("C2").Select

Application.ScreenUpdating = True   
End Sub
```

And here is one of the functions :

I had added a Application.ScreenUpdating = false at the beginning (and the true at the end of course) of each of these functions, but it didn't change anything... 
I withdrew it, thinking that the fact of having a "false then true" makes excel update the screen each time, but it changed nothing :(

```vb
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
'''Changing the first year value
Application.ScreenUpdating = False                                          'Stop the display of the events to gain a LOT of execution time
Call ChangeComboBox1
Application.ScreenUpdating = True                                          'Stop the display of the events to gain a LOT of execution time
End Sub

Public Function ChangeComboBox1()
'''Changing the first year value


'Worksheets("Comparaison").Activate

If ComboBox1.Value > ComboBox2.Value Then 'We want to keep the more ancient in the first combobox
    MsgBox "Please select a year value lower than the the other selected"
    ComboBox1.Value = ComboBox2.Value
Else
    Worksheets("Comparaison").Range("B10").Value = ComboBox1.Value 'Changing the year in the first year box

    count_deliver = 0 'Counting number of delivered cars
    'Computing number of cars in the corresponding year
    nb_line = 3
    Do While Not IsEmpty(Worksheets(ComboBox1.Value).Range("A" & nb_line))
        If Worksheets(ComboBox1.Value).Range("D" & nb_line).Value <> "N/A" Then
            If Year(Worksheets(ComboBox1.Value).Range("D" & nb_line).Value) = CInt(ComboBox1.Value) Then 'Year corresponding to the year of analysis
                count_deliver = count_deliver + 1
            End If
        End If
        nb_line = nb_line + 1
    Loop

    Worksheets("Comparaison").Range("I10").Value = nb_line - 3 'Number of cars in the first year
    Worksheets("Comparaison").Range("N10").Value = count_deliver 'Number of cars in the first year

    Call Format_charts.Update_colors 'Changing colors based on region
    Call Format_charts.Update_prevision 'Displaying previsions if not a full year of analysis
    Call Format_charts.Update_axis 'Changing axis scales based on maximum values
End If

'Bug protection
Worksheets("Comparaison").ComboBox1.Left = 474
Worksheets("Comparaison").ComboBox1.Height = 25.5
Worksheets("Comparaison").ComboBox1.Width = 99
Worksheets("Comparaison").ComboBox1.Top = 64.5

End Function
```

How to make this work properly? I'm pretty sure I loose a looooot of time with these screen updates that should not happen.

I had added a

Thank's by advance !

Comment: Without going through it too much, you are setting `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` after each `Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()` is run. This would obviously refresh the screen mid-macro.

Comment: Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28582897/refresh-all-charts-without-blinking) thread with the same question. Another thing - `Sheet.Activate` ignores `Application.ScreenUpdating` and switching the sheet.

Comment: @JvdV Yes, I understood that, that's why I withdrew the screenupdate, but it didn't change anything :(

Comment: @VitaliyPrushak I know for this, but I'm speaking about the fact that between the pages changes, everything is visible... If I'm right, the "Sheet.activate" will display the sheet change, but the changes realized on the sheet will be hided by the "screen update = false" right?

Comment: @zepeu is there any chance you share an example of the file to reproduce whole process?

Comment: @VitaliyPrushak I'm afraid I can't... I'll try to create a GIF file and share it so you see the things happening...

Comment: @zepeu GIF will not let me step through the code.

Comment: @VitaliyPrushak Right... But basically, you have everything needed in the post here... There is no other "activate" than the ones you see, no "select" at all and no "Application.screenUpdate = True/False" at all except the ones at the begining and end of the main calling code. And, anyway, we see each column being updated one by one...

Comment: Ok, I checked that on a colleague computer, I have Excel 2010, he has excel 2016, This display bug/problem don't happen on his computer :'( So, it seems to be version related or something like that... If someone passing through here got a solution, please, be welcome to give it :)