# VBA SetSourceData function works but gives an error?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a basic histogram called "Chart 1" and want to change the source data with VBA. I use the code the macro recorder gave me

```
Sub setsource()
    Sheets(1).ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("C4:C22")
End Sub
```

but I get "445 Error: Object doesn't support this action." However, the data is changed - so I really don't see whats wrong. The code works and doesn't give an error with other chart types and it obviously works when I do it manually.

Can anybody please help?

Answer (score 1):

Try this, please avoid `Activate` when you can.

```
Worksheets(1).ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart.SeriesCollection.Add _
   Source:=Worksheets(1).Range("C4:C22")
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I tried it but this also throws an error, however a different one as before: "438: Object doesn't support this property or method"

Comment: @msloryg edited the code please try again it should work now !

Comment: now I get the same error as in the beginning.. I am using Excel 2016 btw, I just read in another post that histograms are not completely developed and implemented in this Excel version (you cannot change the bins via VBA for example), maybe that's the problem here as well.

Comment: Can confirm. The code does have the desired effect but throws an error. Method should be wrapped in `On Error Resume Next`, `On Error GoTo 0`

Comment: @msloryg Hi Look at the last com maybe it helps you

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub setsource()
    Sheets(1).ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("C4:C22")
    Sheets(1).ChartObjects("Chart 1").Refresh
End Sub
```

Some good examples of chart refresh can be found in the following question:
[Refresh all charts without blinking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28582897/refresh-all-charts-without-blinking)

Comment: Thank you for your advice, but (of course) I get exactly the same error as before because VBA doesn't like the `ActiveChart.SetSourceData` part.