# VBA Reset label of one or multiple graph on a sheet

Tags: vba

i have a graph multiples graph on a sheet that when i change values sometimes the label of the graph does not show. how can i create a macro that reset label text for the chart. i tried to record a macro but will only update one legend but not all of the labels that i have.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i2UZo.png)

```
Sub Macro1()
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
    ActiveChart.PlotArea.Select
    ActiveChart.ApplyDataLabels
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).DataLabels.Select
    Selection.AutoText = True
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: When you say "label of the graph" are you referring to the data labels or another type of title in the chart? Do you want to update one chart or all the charts?

Comment: I'm referring the data label and I would like to update all the charts.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick example on how you can apply data labels (and even how to position the labels) on any given chart:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Sheet1
    
    Dim chartObj As ChartObject
    For Each chartObj In ws.ChartObjects
        ShowDataLabels chartObj.Chart
    Next chartObj
End Sub

Sub ShowDataLabels(ByRef theChart As Chart, _
                   Optional ByVal show As Boolean = True)
    With theChart
        Dim i As Long
        For i = 1 To .SeriesCollection.Count
            With .SeriesCollection(i)
                .HasDataLabels = True
                .DataLabels.ShowValue = True
                .DataLabels.Position = xlLabelPositionAbove
            End With
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you. is there any way that will reset labels text  since the labels contains value from cells selected range?

Comment: What do you mean by reset?  If the values in the cells change, the data in the chart should update automatically. If that is part of your issue, you can add a `.Refresh` just ***after*** the `Next i` statement (see [this reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.chart.refresh)). Alternatively, I always trust @JonPeltier so check out [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55168786/4717755). That answer refers to animating a chart, but it's still valid to refresh your chart too.