# Excel chart series will not reflect updated data in cells unless I re-select data

Tags: excel, vba, shortcut, excel-2013, automatic-updates

After running a VBA macro which pastes data into cells, my chart does not reflect updated data unless I click “Select Data” and then hit “Ok” or “Cancel”. I don’t have to actually re-select the data ranges - I just have to open and then exit the “Select Data” window, and the chart accurately reflects the updated series.

Is there an automated shortcut or VBA code that would refresh the chart with updated data? We have tried the following:

- Alt F9 or Shift Alt F9
- Force Rebuild code in VBA
- Force calculate code in VBA
- Switching calculation mode from Automatic to Manual back to Automatic

Any additional solutions are greatly appreciated. For additional context, we are working in Excel 2013.

Comment: [Possibly related thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28582897/refresh-all-charts-without-blinking)

Comment: Have you tried adding Charts("ChartName").Refresh and/or Charts("ChartName").SetSourceData(Range) to the end of your macro to possibly trigger the update?